# Java changing multiple panel

Tags: java

i want to create a gui that allow me to change through differents frame, i have a main frame where there are multiple button and when clicking on the button i want to open a new page (like a "display PDF" button), when closing the page created by the button i wantto go back to main frame.

I made a code with creation of differnet Jframe and it works as i want, but i would like to know if there is a bettere and simpler why to do this

```
public class MultiplePanelsExample {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JButton[] buttons;

    public MultiplePanelsExample() {
        // Step 1: Create the main frame and panel
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Main Panel");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();

        // Step 2: Create an array of buttons
        buttons = new JButton[3]; // Adjust the number based on how many buttons you need

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton("Open Panel " + (i + 1));
            mainPanel.add(buttons[i]);
        }

        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        // Step 3: Add action listeners to the buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            final int buttonIndex = i;
            buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    openSecondaryPanel(buttonIndex);
                    mainFrame.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        }


    }

    private void openSecondaryPanel(int buttonIndex) {
        // Step 4: Create the secondary frame and panel
        JFrame secondaryFrame = new JFrame("Panel " + (buttonIndex + 1));
        JPanel secondaryPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextArea tx = new JTextArea("Name ");

        secondaryPanel.add(tx);
        secondaryFrame.add(secondaryPanel);
        secondaryFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        secondaryFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {


                    // NOW we change it to dispose on close..
                    secondaryFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    secondaryFrame.setVisible(false);
                    secondaryFrame.dispose();
                    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        secondaryFrame.setVisible(true);





        secondaryFrame.pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MultiplePanelsExample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for improvements on working code, it's better to ask on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: From design approach perspective, you could use a in-memory messaging style ( https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained )